# Android spinner-like selectors

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am wanting to have option selectors like the AutoTrader app. The way it works, the user must first select a car make from a list and after a make is selected, the user must select a car model under the selected make. I was thinking of implementing a spinner but I like how they have it on their app better. I am not sure how I would implement this. I was thinking about `TextView`s that would open an `AlertDialog` but on the AutoTrader app, you can't choose a model without first choosing a make. I am not sure how I would do this with `TextView`s. Does anyone have any other idea on how I could implement this? Thank you. I provided an image of the AutoTrader app just in case some people aren't familiar with it.
[image]

Comment: so you want us to download this app, and see how it looks? Sorry, but you have to describe it in words.

Comment: @VladMatvienko like I said, I want to have the user select options, like in the image, they select make and model, but they don't seem to use `Spinner`s, it looks something like `TextView`s that when clicked, they open an `AlertDialog`. But the model is inactive until make is chosen, so I am not even sure if they use `TextView`s

Comment: `Spinner` can look like a dialog as well. So that is likely Spinner. Here is a sample of spinner, which opens a dialog to select items http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-1ox1plXuxrs/Ug4iFLJHeEI/AAAAAAAAI2w/Pk1Sfcei_Do/s1600/PopUp_Spinner_02.png . to make Spinner look like that, add `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` to it